# Displaying Multi Data from Multi sensor from 1 gateway using node red

Tags: sensors, node-red, gateway

I need to create a dashboard from multiple data from multiple sensors that has been detected from my gateway. im using mqtt with auto-detect output in node red

I can get the data but i dont know how to separate them according to respective mac address.

for example in time[xxxxxxxxxxx] the obj[0] is dmac[xxxxxxxxxxxxxx] then in the next data obj[0] will be a different dmac.

i need to arrange it sort of like this

dmac: "BC5729028155"
time: "2024-02-11 15:20:43"
rssi: -64
ver: 0
vbatt: 3018
temp: 30.54
humidty: 65.7
x0: -61
y0: -107
z0: 1025

in the dashboard

sorry if this is not clear. i hope u can help.

thank you

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77975950/edit) the question to show the actual JSON structure of the input data and to show what you've tried and how it didn't work.